# Restart MariaDB cluster with Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, mariadb, ansible-playbook

I would like to restart my MariaDB cluster with Ansible.

I applied serial option to run script on servers one by one, but at the end of the script (= after build cluster), I would like to run command on each of these server to carefully restart cluster, which means restart MariaDB server on node one, wait till all are synchronized again, and continue with others, but I don't have idea, which Ansible function (module) should I use.

I tried `delegate_to`, `run_once`, but I have failed when I was trying to run anything on first server as a last step of this playbook. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the wait_for module
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/wait_for_module.html